# Redirect to mobile site on every page or just root index?

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I have mobile detection/redirect on the root index page. But that only helps if a visitor comes through the front door. Does that mean i should use redirection on every page in my site? Or would that be annoying?

Any other suggestions would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to do that. The best way to do this in a DRY way is to have a layout template file which all your views share. Then, you only have to include the redirect script once in your code base.

Comment: This sounds like what i want. I'm not sure how to approach this though. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It depends on how your website is structured. What stack are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure. Currently I'm using windows and just building a "test" site on biz.nf. lol.

Comment: In that case just add the script to every page for now until you start using templates.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly when you build a website you make a css and javascript file that loads up with each file. You should use one javascript file and do that redirection logic there that's how I think it can be done.